# How to access routing parameters in Vue.js - Nuxt - TypeScript application?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm building a website that is based on [Nuxt TypeScript Starter](https://github.com/nuxt-community/typescript-template) template. I've created a dynamically routed page _id.vue inside of my pages folder and I want to have access to that id property inside of my TS class. 
I can access it in my template by writing `{{$route.params.id}}` but when I try to reference `$route` inside of the class I get an error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name '$route'.

Comment: I tried that, but it's throwing an error:
error TS2339: Property '$route' does not exist on type 'default'.

Answer (score 5):

As a simple solution, try importing route from vue-router, like this:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Component from "vue-class-component"
import { Route } from "vue-router"

@Component({})
export default class RoutingExample extends Vue {
    created() {
        console.log(this.$route) // this should not throw TS errors now
    }
        
}
</script>
```

Other solutions I think would require you to [augment the Vue module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation), something similar to what you'd find [here in the Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins).

More Vue + TypeScript examples can be found in this repo: https://github.com/jsonberry/vue-typescript-examples

Comment: Yes, it started working once I imported vue-router but I don't understand why it is :) Why it's not internally imported by Nuxt? Why is it working in template section without importing?

Comment: Without further investigation... my guess is that it's patching the Vue class definition, sort of how the augmentation of the Vue module step is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

better and the right solution for nuxtjs project to find current page URL or param just use

```
{{ $nuxt.$route.name }}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to define `$nuxt`? I get `$nuxt' is not defined` error when trying your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access route.params via fetch function, taking params from the context object that is passed to this function by default:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Component from "nuxt-class-component"
@Component({})
export default class RoutingExample extends Vue {
    fetch ({ store, params }) {
       console.log("params:", params.id);
       ...
    }
}
</script>
```

but the caveat is that params would only be available in that fetch hook, not in other hooks such as created or mounted. So Jason answer is also valid